# python 3.7 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, python, pip, numpy

I have tried to install python 3.7 on my ubuntu 16.04 via [this link](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/). It is 
Installing it without any error and it returns :

```
which python3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

Also I have other python versions (3.5 and 2.7), when I run :

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

but I can not import numpy in 3.7 :

```
python3.7
Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 19 2019, 13:25:43)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>>>
```

I have tried to install numpy :

```
python-numpy is already installed at the requested version (1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1)
```

Furthermore, I don't have this issue in 3.5 :

```
python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong here ?!!! and how could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Python 3.7` installed from source in Ubuntu 16.04 cannot make use of the numpy version from the Ubuntu package system.

You should be able to install it via `pip3.7`:

```
pip3.7 install numpy
```

[See also this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/918335/best-way-to-run-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-which-comes-with-python-3-5).